# Only as an adverb

Tags: parts-of-speech

Why is *only* an adverb instead of an adjective in the following sentences?

- Only Sue and Mark bothered to turn up for the meeting.
- Only an idiot would do that.

Source: https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english-chinese-traditional/only

Comment: Do not answer in comments. Write an answer: that's how Stack Exchange works. If you want to migrate this question elsewhere, vote to do that. I've deleted the two conflicting comments.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Does it matter where you put “only”?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/111817/does-it-matter-where-you-put-only) There are other threads also dealing with 'only'. Personally, I see it as so far from being either an adjective or an adverb that I prefer the class 'limiting modifiers / focus particles'.

Comment: See also [Do adverbs only 'describe' verbs?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/101188/do-adverbs-only-describe-verbs). Focusing modifiers aren't mentioned specifically, but the arguable  inappropriateness of the 'adverb _dustbin class_' is discussed.

Comment: I'm voting to re-open the question. It does not ask about the position of "only" in a clause, but asks why "only" is an adverb, not an adjective, in the examples cited.

Comment: The distinction between the focusing adverb "only" and the adjective "only" is a tricky one, and well worth discussing on ELU.

Comment: @BillJ Ah, now that you too consider this stuff tricky , it's a big, big relief. I thought I'd screwed up a simple grammatical concept. And thank you for your answer!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> [1] *[Only Sue and Mark] bothered to turn up for the meeting*.
>
> [2] *[Only an idiot] would do that.*

In both examples, "only" is an adverb functioning as a focusing modifier in the bracketed noun phrases.

Focusing adverbs modify a wide range of constructions, including noun phrases, but they do not modify nouns or nominals, as opposed to noun phrases.

> [3] *I don't eat meat, but [only fish]*.

Here, fish is an NP consisting of just a noun. You could have [4] but not [5]

> [4] *I eat meat, but [only this kind of fish].*
>
> [5] * *I eat meat but this [only kind of fish].*

In [5] "kind of fish" is a nominal and hence the sentence is ungrammatical.

However, in an appropriate construction "only" can modify a nominal, in which case it is not an adverb but an adjective, as in [6]

> [6] *My [only reservation] is the cost.*

where "only" modifies the nominal "reservation".

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I'm a little confused when you say "focusing adverbs modify a wide range of constructions, including noun phrases, but they do not modify nouns or nominals, as opposed to noun phrases." Doesn't "only" modify the noun "fish" in [3]?   Like you said, a noun phrase can consist of just a noun, and so they are not distinct categories?

Comment: @Ana NP and nominal are distinct categories. A nominal is the unit intermediate between the NP and the noun -- it's the noun phrase minus the determiner. "Fish" in [3] is not a nominal but an NP, whereas "reservation" is a nominal in [6], so "only" is an adjective, not a focusing adverb.

Comment: I always thought of them as overlapping categories, but now I see what you mean. Thank you very much for your explanation!

Answer (score 4):

> Only Sue and Mark bothered to turn up for the meeting.

Here, we can replace "only" with **merely, solely, exclusively** - You will note all are adverbs: we cannot use mere, sole, exclusive.

**Only** fronts the whole main clause as a free modifier. The same applies to the second.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer!